# More rewrite error 500

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The following .htaccess rules are causing an error 500 configuration error:

```
RewriteEngine On    

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} admin\.localhost$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /admin.php/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.google.com [L,NC]
```

The problem line is the middle one. If I comment it out it works fine.
The aim is to catch everything on http://admin.localhost and pass it all to the admin.php for handling. The bottom line is just to test that the rule is working and everything has been caught by the second line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop rewriting when request URI is already `admin.php`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin\.localhost$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!admin\.php/).*)$ admin.php/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: That causes it to miss the second rule and go to Google. To test it I'm accessing http:\\admin.localhost so it isn't already admin.php. The defaultindex for the vhost is admin.php so in theiory it is but if I change the line to direct to index.php it still gives an error 500.

Comment: Other than 'RewriteEngine On' at the top, that's it. It will have other rules for additional subdomains but not ATM

Comment: This rule is already tested and working. It will skip the rule ONLY if REQUEST_URI already starts with `/admin.php/`

Comment: In which case it will always skip the rule as the default index is admin.php. Why don't you think my rule is working.

Comment: If `DirectoryIndex` is set to `admin.php`  shouldn't your .htaccess be showing it somewhere? However having `DirectoryIndex` as `admin.php` won't affect this rule because this rule is skipping `admin.php/` (slash in the end)

Comment: DirectoryIndex is set in the apache config.